# Reading task from English State Exam in Russia

Tags: reading, reading-comprehension

I'm not sure whether it is appropriate to ask questions like the following one on StackExchange, but you are my only hope.

Here's an abstract of reading task and a question taken from 2019 Russian National Exam in English.

> ...Our new auditorium is one shining example that we are proud to
>   support. Not only is this facility a marvel of world-class
>   architecture and programming, it also strives to make the arts
>   accessible to all citizens. These experiences spark curiosity and
>   imagination in audiences, young and old, to remind us what it means to
>   be alive in this era of technology and separation.
>
> **It is implied that the new auditorium supports an education program in ..**
>
> 1. arts.
> 2. architecture.
> 3. technology.
> 4. programming.

Which answer is correct? I suppose, it is neither architecture nor programming because those two were mentioned to describe the interior and facilities the new auditorium has. Having two options left, I guess the answer is arts.

Am I right? Could you, please, clarify?

Comment: Just so you know, questions like these are usually welcome here, provided that (a) you tell us where the question comes from, and (b) you tell us what thoughts or notions you have about the question. (In other words, don't just copy a question, and ask "Which is the correct answer?") You have done both of these things in this question, so I think your question should be fine.

Comment: The English in the given text is not as good as it might be. For example "it also strives to make the arts accessible". The antecedent of "it" is 'this facility" but it is rather unusual to write that a facility "strives".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the answer would be the arts. The key phrase here is "it also strives to make the arts accessible to all citizens." This shows that the purpose of the auditorium is making the arts accessible to people - accessible implying that it is a goal to let more people understand the arts, or in other words, to educate people in the arts. It's not a certainty that there is an arts educational programme from just the text, but since the question is only asking for an implication, this would be the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit subjective, but I would go with "arts". While the other three subjects are mentioned, only arts is explicitly presented as being something being provided to people. All buildings, by definition, involve architecture, so the mention of that subject doesn't necessarily lead to the conclusion that that is the focus of the building (of course, architecture is itself an art form, but I guess we should ignore that). The mention of "programming" is a bit odd, and makes me question whether this was written by a native speaker. But like architecture, programming seems to be presented as something that the auditorium exemplifies, rather than necessarily provides education in. And while "technology" is mentioned, it actually seems to be contrasted with the purpose of the auditorium: the implication is that because we spend so much time around technology (and "separation"), we need the auditorium to remind us of what it feels to be "alive". Contrasting feeling "alive" to machines/technology and isolation, in addition to references to sparking "curiosity" and "imagination", all support the inference that this building is directed towards artistic purposes. So if I have to choose between those four options, I would go with "arts", but it does still require some degree of making inferences rather than being clearly supported by the text.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! And yes, I can't but agree with you. The authenticity of the text given is a big question.